# Configuration file XML - Parsing Library C/C++ - Android, IOS, Desktop

Tags: android, xml, parsing, libxml2

I have a large C program which needs to communicate some XML files to Java/Obj-C and other languages.  99% of the program business logic is in C/C++ mix.  Java, Obj-C all have a way to parse XML and in most cases I'll be using HTML5 and Javascript (via PhoneGap) to parse the XML on that end.  The part that is frustrating is finding a decent C or C++ library that compiles on each platform and is relatively straight forward to use.

I've looked into libxml2 first.  It is not easy to get compiling for Android at least, required ICU4 to get working.  I then checked out libroxml, unfortunately its xml modification core is weak at best.

Does anyone have a tip for a nice XML Parsing library that isn't hell to compile or use?  That supports modification of the XML file?  Do I need to be concerned about language support (unicode)?

Answer (score 0):

TinyXML seems like the way to go.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/

Small, supports modification of the tree, utf8 and compiles easily (just a few files, no platform dependencies).